# How I get the string from the combination of the last part of some paths?

Tags: python

First of all, I have this list of tuples:

```
paths = [('/User/folder/fileA.png', '/User/folder/fileB.png'), ('/User/folder/fileC.png', '/User/folder/fileD.png'), ('/User/folder/fileE.png', '/User/folder/fileF.png') ]
```

And my objective would be to get a function that could give me the string of the combined files:

```
print(combinations)

fileA_fileB
fileC_fileD
fileE_fileF
```

I have tried to fix it with the pathlib module but I can't iterate through the list. Any ideas? Thank you very much in advance

Comment: can you check the solution? @Fran

Comment: It works ;) thank you @python_user

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert them to `Path` objects then get the name using `Path.stem`. You can of course concatenate them how you wish, adding an underscore in your case. Something like `f'{Path(i).stem}_{Path(j).stem}'`.

```
from pathlib import Path

paths = [('/User/folder/fileA.png', '/User/folder/fileB.png'), ('/User/folder/fileC.png', '/User/folder/fileD.png'), ('/User/folder/fileE.png', '/User/folder/fileF.png') ]
res = [Path(i).stem + Path(j).stem for i, j in paths]

for i in res:
    print(i)
```

Output

```
fileAfileB
fileCfileD
fileEfileF
```